# MongoDB server is not recognizing connection from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB database through Jupyter Notebpok script.

However, the status on MongoDB server remains as "waiting for connections on port 27017".

I tried the following:

1-run "mongod" on cmd

2-run the script on JupyterNotebook:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
conn = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

Is this enough for establishing the connection? Is there any specifics regarding the local where I should run the scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm that your DB is on port 27017? You can find this in the GUI if you have it downloaded.

Comment: Hi ParalysisByAnalysis. Yes, I could find the DB on port 27017 by using GUI...

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
conn = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
```

If that doesnt work, try:

```
conn = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
```

You can also open up MongoDB's GUI and see if you can connect there.  You may be able to find it by searching "MongoDB" and it may have "Compass Community" after it.

Comment: Hi, I tried both but for some reason, nothing on the  command prompt has changed. The "status" remains as "waiting for connection"...

Comment: ok next question...have you tried with the db name following the forward slash? `conn = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/<insert_db_name>')`

Comment: I tried just now and nothing's changed. It seems the command prompt isn't being updated... I will post the print screen from the GUI used so we can check that the database "cadastrodb" was really created.

Answer (score 0):

[image: GUI print]

*I tried just now and nothing's changed. It seems the command prompt isn't being updated... I will post the print screen from the GUI used so we can check that the database "cadastrodb" was really created.*